# Supernatural Season 11, Episode 15: Why the difference in demon eye color?

Tags: supernatural

So I noticed that the (non-recurring) demon character featured in *Supernatural* Season 11, Episode 15 ("Beyond the Mat") flashes his "demon" eye color for a moment in the middle of the episode. (To clarify, this is the blonde demon who's manipulating the WWE-type boxer.)

But instead of the usual "eyes turn completely black" gig, this demon's eyes turn red. This difference is never addressed in-episode or in the episodes directly following it. Granted, I haven't finished watching Season 11, but that seems like an awful long time to go without the show even acknowledging that something was different.

Does anybody have any idea why this particular demon had red eyes instead of black? Am I forgetting some demon backstory for the Supernatural universe that would explain this difference?

Comment: I haven't seen that particular episode, but I think @thatoneguy 's answer is probably right.     http://www.fanpop.com/clubs/supernatural/articles/76336/title/demons-supernatural

Answer (score 4):

I believe the reason that demon's eyes turn red is because he was a "Cross-road" demon. Cross-road demons have red eyes. For eg. look at Crowley. Before he was king of hell, he was a cross-road demon, hence he has red eyes as well.

Cross-road demons are hell's salesmen. They make deals with humans. That wrestler made a deal, hence he's dealing with a cross-road demon.

Comment: Agreed. The same thing happened with the demon in "Season Seven, Time for a Wedding!" (S7E8).

Answer (score 1):

The different eye colours signify the demon's status and power level within the hierarchy of Hell. The colours used are: White, Yellow, Red and Black. Interestingly, while the black-eyed demons tend to be the lowest level of demon there is a more powerful type of demon which also has black eyes:

> the Knights of Hell, hand-picked by Lucifer and trained by Cain - the first knight

For the full run-down, check [this page](https://supernatural.fandom.com/wiki/Demons#Types_of_Demons) out.